# Does Mule community edition v3.3.0 support shutdownTimeout

Tags: mule, mule-component

Does Mule community edition v3.3.0 support shutdownTimeout feature?

The documentation at http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Global+Settings+Configuration+Reference suggests that the shutdowntimeout feature is supported from v2.2.0 but I am not able to get that shutdownTimeout feature to work?

Does anybody has implemented that shutdown feature in Mule v3.3.0 CE? Please help me in configuring that and get that feature to work.

Is this feature available only for EE or it is available in CE too?

Comment: The code of Mule CE has shutdownTimeout in many places: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=shutdownTimeout What makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks David for the response. I came across few links over the net which were talking about some problem related to shutdown timeout not working. So was skeptical if it would work in Mule CE v3.3.0.  http://mule.1045714.n5.nabble.com/mule-jira-MULE-6816-Shutdown-timeout-is-not-respected-td5717705.html,  https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-3518: Need to support the graceful shutdown feature,  https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6816: Shutdown timeout is not respected, https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-3688: Graceful/Forceful shutdown with timeouts

Comment: Where do u configure the shutdownTimeout? Is it in the wrapper.conf or the wrapper-additional.conf as something like wrapper.java.additional.<n>=-Dmule.shutdownTimeout=40000

Comment: In the configuration section of your Mule XML configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the attribute is present and taken into account in 3.3.0.
In order to use it you should add a configuration tag in your config file and set a value for that attribute:

```
<mule>
...
  <configuration shutdownTimeout="60000" />
...
```

However, as reported in https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6816 depending on the message processors present in your flow, the shutdown process could fail, if that's the case you could review the code changes in the fix and apply them.

What problem are you facing?

Regards,
Marcos

Comment: Thanks Marcos for the response. I thought that the shutdownTimeout is a Mule container level feature and not an application level feature. I was trying to add this attribute to the wrapper.conf and wrapper-additional.conf in /mule/conf directory. Am I wrong here?